# How do I take advantage of account linking in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm having some trouble understanding exactly what linking accounts does in Firestore, and how that informs data structure in the DB.

For example, I am currently logging in users anonymously by default, and allowing them to save "favorites" under their anonymous UID. Something like the following:

```
export const saveFav = await (favData) => {
  const user = auth.currentUser;
  const favStore = "Users/" + user.uid + "/Favorites";
  const newFav = doc(collection(db, favStore));
  await addDoc(newFav, favData);
}
```

I'd like for the user to be able to add favorites as an anonymous user, and then save those favorites if they choose to sign in through a provider. Something like this:

```
const firstTimeLogin = async (uid) => {
  const q = query(collection(db, "Users"), where(documentId(), "==", uid));
  const res = await getDocs(q);
  return !res.empty
};

export const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
  const prevUser = auth.currentUser; // Store for merging data

  const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
        // Link anonymous account and new user
        try {
            if (firstTimeLogin(result.user.uid) && prevUser.isAnonymous) {
                linkWithCredential(prevUser, GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result));
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // ...
    });
};
```

(I'm sorry about the .then/try mish-mash. I'm still learning JavaScript syntax.)

I expected that Firestore would start to use the same UID for the now-linked (I think) anonymous and Google users. However when I console log them both they seem distinct.

Does anyone know what exactly linking accounts changes? I can see in the docs that we are meant to merge data for the two users in the store ourselves. If the user were to link another third-party account (e.g. Twitter), does anyone know how Firestore wants us to grab the same data for them from the DB?

Comment: [Account linking](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) is a feature of Firebase Authentication, not of Firestore. It may be easier to isolate the problem without involving Firestore in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `signInWithPopup` with the `GoogleAuthProvider`, which (as the API name says) signs the user in with Google - creating a second user profile. If you want to link the `GoogleAuthProvider` to the existing user profile, call `linkWithPopup` as shown in this code sample from step 3 of the documentation on [linking federated auth provider credentials to a user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-federated-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account).

```
import { getAuth, linkWithRedirect, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

const auth = getAuth();
linkWithRedirect(auth.currentUser, provider)
  .then(/* ... */)
  .catch(/* ... */);
```

Comment: Hi Frank - thank you for the response! In that code snippet I was attempting to link the accounts programmatically, after a first-time login, using `linkWithCredential`. However I've changed tack on that - I'm just going to replace the anonymous user with the Google user if it is a first time login. I still am unclear though on how I can retrieve the same data from the db for linked users. Do you know how we're intended to achieve that? I'm guessing my users should be identified by something other than UID in my DB if UID will be different for each account, even if they are linked.

Comment: You will either have to maintain a mapping between the various UIDs for the same user, or update all existing data to use the new (non-anonymous) UID for the user.

Comment: Ok got it, that seems straightforward. If that's the case though, I'm confused as to the purpose of the `linkWith...` functions in Firebase. Do they just serve as a way to prompt a user for their credentials, even if they're already signed-in?

Comment: `linkWithCredential` allows you to associate multiple providers with a single user profile. So folks can sign in to the same profile/UID with any of the associated providers.